# ArcMap 10: How do I escape certain characters when labeling?

Tags: arcmap, labeling, vbscript

I am labeling certain Oil & Gas areas by Operator in ArcMap 10, using this expression:

"" & [OPERATOR] & "" & vbNewline & "" &  [UNIT_NAME] & ""

[image]

The only problem is that when the operator includes an ampersand (&), the label messes up because it's reading it as part of the expression, and ends up looking like it does in the screenshot below.

I know that in PHP (from my experience programming unrelated to GIS), there is a way to escape certain characters, but I haven't been able to find it in VBScript.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdKxB.png

Comment: http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/1104/files/vbscript_label.pdf

Answer (score 8):

You can replace them in your script with the syntax

```
Function FindLabel ([LABELFIELD])
  NewString = Replace([LABELFIELD],"&","&amp;")  
  FindLabel = "<ITA>" & NewString & "</ITA>"
End Function
```

Comment: Ok so here's what I changed my expression to, but it's still not working:
<br />
<br />
`Function FindLabel ( [OPERATOR], [UNIT_NAME] )
  NewString = Replace ([OPERATOR],"&","&amp;")
  FindLabel = "<FNT size='8'>" & [OPERATOR] & "</FNT>" & vbNewline & "<BOL>" &  [UNIT_NAME] & "</BOL>"
End Function'`

Comment: Because you have assigned the "replace" to a variable called "NewString", you have to replace [OPERATOR] in the findlabel portion to the variable: NewString.

Comment: This script works for me `Function FindLabel ( [MODIFIER1], [TYPE] )
  NewString = Replace( [MODIFIER1] ,"&","&amp;")  
  FindLabel = "<FNT size='8'>" & NewString & "</FNT>" & vbNewline & "<BOL>" & [TYPE] & "</BOL>"
End Function` As SaultDon as said

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the question as answered.