# Using Label Expression with Text Formatting Tags and Ampersand

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, arcgis-10.2

I am using a Label Expression to label a parcel layer.  The expression is:

```
"<FNT name=""Arial"" size=""12"">" & [Owners_Nam] & "</FNT>"
```

This works correctly for some labels, but any [Owners_Name] field that has an "&" in it, such as between two owners names (Smith, John & Sue), does not show up correctly.  The parcel is labeled as:

```
<FNT name="Arial" size="12">Smith, John & Sue</FNT>
```

Is there any way to solve this without removing the "&" from the [Owner Name] field?

I know how to replace the & in Field Calculator; I would just like to preserve the original field text.  I've had this same problem in the past using the `<BOL>` tag too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ampersand is a special character, in order to insert one into a text box or a label you should use the code `&amp;` instead. The less-than symbol is the same way, if you need to use one of those in your label, use the code `&lt;`

Related: [ArcMap 10: How do I escape certain characters when labeling?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28556/arcmap-10-how-do-i-escape-certain-characters-when-labeling/28558#28558)

Comment: Thanks.  I tested this with a few parcels - changing the text in the field to include `&amp` instead of just `&` but then the `&amp` appears in my label and the label still does not display correctly.  I'm using the VBScript parser.  The `&` that I want to see in the final product is in the field already, not something I'm entering in the label expression.

Comment: Looks like you're missing the semicolon at the end, the actual code should be `&amp;`