# On 4 of 74 Data Driven Pages dynamic text box prints out the codes instead of implementing them?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages, formatting

I am using Data Driven Pages in ArcGIS Desktop.

Here's the text box entry:

```
<UND>PWS Well Identification</UND>
<BOL>PWS Name:</BOL> <dyn type="page" property="attribute" field="OwnerID" domainlookup="true"/>
<BOL>Primary Station Code:</BOL> <dyn type="page" property="attribute" field="PS_CODE" domainlookup="true"/>
<BOL>Owner Well Name: </BOL> <dyn type="page" property="attribute" field="SOURCE_NAM" domainlookup="true"/>
```

On almost all of the DDP pages, the underlines and bolds are implemented properly, where the underlined bits are underlined and bold bits are bolded, but on 4 of them, it looks like this:

```
<UND>PWS Well Identification</UND>
<BOL>PWS Name:</BOL> Turlock Golf & Country Club
<BOL>Primary Station Code:</BOL> 2400078-001
<BOL>Owner Well Name: </BOL> WELL #1 - CLUBHOUSE/POOL AREA
```

Its printing out the codes, but its going and getting the information from the attribute table like its supposed to.

That's on 4 of the 74 pages. the rest work normal.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: This isn't an ArcGIS support forum, please list the software you're using so it can be directed to the right audience.

Comment: Do any of the attributes you are reading have special characters? An ampersand (&) for example will break ArcGIS's text formatting.

Comment: Do you need to have all four stacked lines of text to demonstrate this?  If not can you reduce your code snippet to be just one line so that we can focus our attention on what may be in the attribute table for just that field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Use Label Expression with Text Formatting Tags](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80434/how-to-use-label-expression-with-text-formatting-tags)

Comment: I'll have to wait until Tuesday to check it, but I am sure Keagan has it right. Thanks!In the future, it seems like people who don't get the question could just refrain from answering. DDP, text formatting, all that is pretty complicated stuff and if you are not familiar with the details, its not really worth commenting. the question was perfectly clear to anyone who knows how the DDP dynamic text works. This reminded me of that Amazon feature where people can ask quesitons about a product before they buy it and half the answers are "I dont know, I haven't taken it out of the box yet".

Answer (score 1):

If this is the output:

> PWS Well Identification PWS Name: Turlock Golf &
>   Country Club Primary Station Code: 2400078-001 Owner
>   Well Name:  WELL #1 - CLUBHOUSE/POOL AREA

The the "&" will break the ESRI Coding. 
Try replacing that in the attribute table.