# Bolding Text String Not Working in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, formatting, text-element

I am using ArcMap 10.5 with an Advanced level license.

I am wanting a portion of my text box to be bold. I clicked Insert --> Text. When I type `<bol>` it literally shows up on my text box as `<bol>`. I have searched everywhere for recommendations, tried adding quotation marks and nothing works.

[image]

Comment: Normally this happens when your text box also has a special character in it that requires a special code to use, like an ampersand, but I don't see anything like that here. It looks like it should work. Try just using the <BOL> tags and a single piece of text in between, no colons, periods, extra lines, etc. and if that works, add pieces one by one until it breaks.

Comment: @Dan C Great idea! I deleted everything and when I add an ampersand, the formatting suddenly stops working. (I deleted the text in the screenshot that shows the ampersand because of confidentiality.) Any ideas why a random ampersand would mess up the formatting?

Comment: The ampersand and a few other characters are special in ArcGIS text boxes, because they are used for text formatting. If you want to add an ampersand to a text box, you have to use the code `&amp;` instead:  [How to Use Label Expression with Text Formatting Tags](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80434/how-to-use-label-expression-with-text-formatting-tags)

Answer (score 0):

I tried what you describe in your question using ArcMap 10.8 and I see the expected bolding in my text element.

[image]

I would not expect this behaviour to have changed since ArcMap 10.5.

I suspect there is more in your text box than we can see, and that the [comment from @DanC](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/390312/bolding-text-string-not-working/390320#comment639226_390312) may provide the explanation:

> The ampersand and a few other characters are special in ArcGIS text
> boxes, because they are used for text formatting. If you want to add
> an ampersand to a text box, you have to use the code `&amp;` instead:
> [How to Use Label Expression with Text Formatting
> Tags](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80434/how-to-use-label-expression-with-text-formatting-tags)