# Formatting tag, <ITA></ITA> for italics not working in ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro legend

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, legend

I've been editing a species name in the legend regularly for the past few months of mapping by using:

```
<ITA>speciesname</ITA>, and then the rest of the label
```

For some reason, this method is working for some labels and not working for others. In the legend, some labels literally read `<ITA>Arenaria interpres</ITA>, XYZ...`
and some read:
*Calidris canutus*, XYZ

So the legend is reading the feature labels correctly sometimes and incorrectly other times.
Info on formatting tags is here:
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-text/formatting-tags-available-in-arcmap.htm

I have tried different fonts (arial, calibri, times new roman), I have also tried solving this in ArcGIS Pro by importing the .mxd to the ArcGIS Pro project with the same result. I have had this problem in separate .mxds as well.

Has anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: So had you converted your legend to a graphic to be applying those HTML tags?

Comment: Check your data fields in the table for formatting characters, e.g., single or double quotes or slashes.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have special characters in any of the labels?  If so, there are multiple similar and/or duplicate answers availble [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=formatting%20tags); this one summarizes the (potential) solution best:

[Using Label Expression with Text Formatting Tags and Ampersand](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/80435/90872)

Answer (score 0):

In the label, I have the symbol `&`.  The solution was to replace the `&` symbol with the `&amp;` entity.

Comment: Do you mean replace the `&` character with the `&amp;` entity?  at the moment the answer doesn't make sense

Comment: @nmtoken yes he does. `&amp;` is actually contained in the answer, but the website converted it to `&`.

Comment: works great, thank you!